# how to find the path for libcudart.so?

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, gpu, cuda

I'm trying to install Tensorflow GPU version and I'm stuck at this.
I've installed nvidia-cuda-toolkit by running

```
 sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and it downloaded fine. But i'm unable to locate this libcudart.so

```
Please specify which gcc nvcc should use as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: /usr/bin/gcc
Please specify the Cuda SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to use system default]: 
Please specify the location where CUDA  toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: /usr/local/cuda
Invalid path to CUDA  toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so cannot be found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144698/find-a-file-using-the-terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best way but I had the same issue and this helped.

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64 /usr`

Verify the link from `/usr` with `ls -l lib64`

`lib64 -> /usr/local/cuda/lib64`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that, you have exported wrong path.

So, On terminal type: `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64`

ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line

If this don't work try: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin`
This will set environmental path.

Comment: this is definitely the right answer. note that the path `/usr/local/cuda` is potentially optional with some nvidia installers, so if you dont have that path, just use `/usr/local/cuda-10.0`

Comment: i don't havef any of these paths

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 18.04 and want to get TensorFlow with GPU support installed, there is a deb package for that in the Lambda Stack repository.

You can install the repository and the package with this line:

```
LAMBDA_REPO=$(mktemp) && \
wget -O${LAMBDA_REPO} https://lambdal.com/static/files/lambda-stack-repo.deb && \
sudo dpkg -i ${LAMBDA_REPO} && rm -f ${LAMBDA_REPO} && \
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y lambda-stack-cuda
```

What it does:

1. Download and installs the Lambda Stack Repository (essentially adds a file to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/)
2. Updates apt and installs the `lambda-stack-cuda` package.
3. Installs CUDA, Drivers, CuDNN, and TensorFlow with CuDNN and GPU support into the proper system level directories. You won't need to modify your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `PATH` as the shared libraries are placed in directories that `ld` already checks at link time.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that Lambda Stack doesn't set the the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CUDA_HOME` environment variables. Any reason why the installer doesn't do this?

Comment: It’s because we properly place the library .so files in locations where ‘ld’ already looks.