# Xubuntu new install: need scanner driver

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, scanner

Apologies if this is obvious, but I am in a hurry, need answer quickly...

Just installed XFCE, most hardware is good so far

NEED to scan some documents right now, cannot figure out how to do that.

I downloaded driver from Epson (Epson 1660 perfection scanner) that is correct for my 32bit chip and ubuntu.

Don't know what to do now!

Readme file says

```
Change to the folder where you downloaded this scanner driver bundle,
extract it and install all components with

::

   tar xaf iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb.tar.gz
   cd iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb
   ./install.sh

in a terminal window.

You will be asked for your password to acquire the privileges needed
to install software on your system.  This works the same way as with
your regular software installation procedure.
```

May be dumb question , but can you step by step me to how "change to the folder"?  Or, I guess I am saying what is the correct terminal language to take care of this post haste?

I pasted the whole string, and that did not work, and then I pasted just "./install.sh" which also didn't work.

((I will be learning how to use this OS like a normal person starting tomorrow, but need my scanner today))

Comment: Neither whole string which is made of 3 distinct commands would work nor just install.sh alone. You don't need the frist part because you can extract it simply by right-click > Extract here. The change to folder is the part starting with cd and that you must do in terminal.

Comment: so you are saying type ":~$  cd iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb ./install.sh"  ? ":~$ cd iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb "?  Neither works...I think there is something simple I am not grasping here!

Comment: Finding a file is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144698/find-a-file-using-the-terminal

Comment: @rexpeatram - Check the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps needed to install using the file you already downloaded.

1. Double-click `iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb.tar.gz` and extract to your home folder (it's the same folder that contains Documents, Music, etc.); you should see there a new folder with the name `iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb`
2. Open the terminal (it opens by default in your home folder) and do `cd iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb`, press Enter; you're now at the `iscan-bundle-1.0.2.x86.deb` folder
3. Run the installer script with `./install.sh` (./ indicates the file install.sh is inside the folder you're already in)